# How do I figure out where a named lifetime comes from?

Tags: rust, lifetime, raw-pointer

I'm reading [the code of rust-sdl2](https://rust-sdl2.github.io/rust-sdl2/src/sdl2/render.rs.html#1490-1493) and there's this `Texture` struct:

```
pub struct Texture<'r> {
    raw: *mut sys::SDL_Texture,
    _marker: PhantomData<&'r ()>,
}
```

How do I know where the `'r` lifetime comes from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the struct was declared like this, then Rust would be able to automatically ensure memory safety:

```
pub struct Texture<'r> {
    raw: &'r mut sys::SDL_Texture,
}
```

Since the `SDL_Texture` is managed outside of Rust code this isn't possible because a raw pointer is needed. The lifetime on the `Texture` is there to add a memory-safe abstraction around an unsafe data structure.

The crate manages the creation of `Texture`s, and ensures that the lifetimes are always "correct". The lifetime is there to ensure that the texture does not outlive the inner `SDL_Texture`, which is only referenced by raw pointer.

You cannot create a `Texture` yourself, except by unsafe functions. If you were to call `TextureCreator::raw_create_texture` you'd have to meet all requirements on that lifetime yourself. Instead, the *safe* method `create_texture` constructs a `Texture`, while guaranteeing memory safety.

The type signature of `create_texture` is:

```
pub fn create_texture<F>(
    &self,
    format: F,
    access: TextureAccess,
    width: u32,
    height: u32,
) -> Result<Texture, TextureValueError>
where
    F: Into<Option<PixelFormatEnum>>,
```

Some lifetimes are elided. According to Rust's [lifetime elision rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/lifetime-elision.html), this can be written more explicitly as:

```
pub fn create_texture<'r, F>(
    &'r self,
    format: F,
    access: TextureAccess,
    width: u32,
    height: u32,
) -> Result<Texture<'r>, TextureValueError>
where
    F: Into<Option<PixelFormatEnum>>,
```

The lifetime annotations express a referential dependency between `self` and the `Texture`. The returned `Texture` is therefore not allowed to outlive the `TextureCreator`.

Comment: thank you. I had looked at that method and didn't see any named lifetimes, which confused me.